# Rails 3 force localization language for specific text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, rails-i18n

Any way to force the translation to a specific language only for some text. Something like:

```
t("my.text",:fr)
```

The reason is that i want the user to be able to change the language of their content but not the site interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It could be done this way:

```
I18n.t :foo, :locale => :fr
```

equivalent too:

```
t("my.text", :locale => :fr)
```

Comment: Is there any way of the displayed translations automatically switching between languages without having to reload a page? So if I would change a page's language in Javascript, that it will show that using the Rails translation method. (Reloading the page is not possible in this case)

Answer (score 6):

```
t("my.text", locale: :fr)
```

More options [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/svenfuchs/i18n/master/I18n/Base#translate-instance_method)